# how to use horizontal scroll feature in tinyscroll plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using tiny scroll bar function from http://baijs.com/tinyscrollbar/ , Documentation said we can use the horizontal feature by setting the x axis like below

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
               $("#scrollbar1").tinyscrollbar({ axis: "x"});
            });
```

But Only vertical is working for me , not horizontal.I want to make it work with horizontal scrollbar and custom width.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/874pzsvL/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the CSS for the horizontal. Check this [link](http://baijs.com/tinyscrollbar/css/tinyscrollbar.css) and search for `#scrollbar2`. In the fiddle I replaced the CSS and renamed scrollbar1 to scrollbar2 as their CSS is targetting `#scrollbar2` for horizontal styling.

```
/* scrollbar2 */
#scrollbar2
{
    width:251px;
    margin:0 0 10px;
}

#scrollbar2 .viewport
{
    width:236px;
    height:125px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}

#scrollbar2 .overview
{
    list-style:none;
    width:1416px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}

#scrollbar2 .overview img
{
    float:left;
}

#scrollbar2 .scrollbar
{
    background:transparent url(../images/bg-scrollbar-track-x.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 0 5px;
    clear:both;
    height:15px;
}

#scrollbar2 .track
{
    background:transparent url(../images/bg-scrollbar-trackend-x.png) no-repeat 100% 0;
    width:100%;
    height:15px;
    position:relative;
}

#scrollbar2 .thumb
{
    background:transparent url(../images/bg-scrollbar-thumb-x.png) no-repeat 100% 50%;
    height:25px;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:-5px;
}

#scrollbar2 .thumb .end
{
    background:transparent url(../images/bg-scrollbar-thumb-x.png) no-repeat 0 50%;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:25px;
    width:5px;
}

#scrollbar2 .disable
{
    display:none;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/874pzsvL/1/)

Comment: hey thanks alot , how can i make the scrollbar show under the text...not on TOP

Comment: Put the `.scrollbar` div below the viewport like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/874pzsvL/2/)